# ambiguous column name id in SQL Server Query in c#

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
select 
    Gid, Class, GroupName 
from 
    Class, Group1 
where 
    Class.Gid = Group1.Gid
```

This query correctly execute in DB but gives error in program?

Comment: i already take class.gid

Comment: It is not possible to have an ambiguous column error if they are all qualified with either the table name or alias in _all_ places in the query. Try the query that I posted. If you still have an error, then the query that is running is not the one you think it is.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2):

You have same column in both table, so give alias of each column
like

User Inner join, this type of coding is old style.

```
select 
       g1.Gid,
       cl.Class,
       g1.GroupName 
from 
     Class cl 
     inner join Group1 g1 
     on cl.Gid=g1.Gid
```

Answer (score 2):

As the field `Gid` exists in both tables, you have to specify which one you want to select. So the minium change to make the query work would be:

```
select Class.Gid,Class,GroupName from Class,Group1 where Class.Gid=Group1.Gid
```

It's a good idea to specify the table for each field, that makes it easier to see where the data comes from, and it makes the query less sensetive to table layout changes. You can use alases to keep that from making the code cluttered with table names.

Also, you should use the `join` keyword to join tables, the old way of joining is deprecated in later versions of the database engine.

```
select
  c.Gid,
  g.Class,
  g.GroupName
from
  Class c
  inner join Group1 g on c.Gid = g.Gid
```

Answer (score 1):

Use table aliases and proper JOIN syntax:

```
SELECT cl.Gid, cl.Class, gr.GroupName
FROM   Class cl
INNER JOIN Group1 gr
        ON cl.[Gid] = gr.[Gid];
```

The ambiguous column is `Gid` since it exists in both tables but is referenced in the SELECT list without specifying which table it should be pulled from.

For readability, it is best to use more than a single character as the alias. Hence "cl" and "gr" are better in the long-run than "c" and "g".

Comment: @Oldfart Yes, they are optional, but also a very good practice to get in the habit of. No need to copy full table names across all of the places it will be used. Queries are much easier to read when using decent (i.e. more than 1 letter) aliases.

Comment: I have worked for many that take the exact opposite view on readability grounds

Comment: @Oldfart Well, there is a degree to which this is just preference, but I kinda want to propose that using full table names everywhere suggests either poor table naming conventions or poor table alias naming conventions ;-). I have worked on large, complex systems with non-cryptic but also non-short table names and aliases that are usually acronyms are far more readable than 15 - 20 character table names repeated 50 times in a query ;-).

Comment: @Oldfart What I was saying at the end of my last comment is: if I was working with cryptic table names such as "GD_QTR_RSLT" then maybe I would prefer the table name. But then again, I might still prefer an alias such as "results" given how horrible that table naming convention is ;-).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Class and Group1 both have a GID property. Use aliases to distinguish the two properties:

```
select c.Gid, c.Class, g.Gid, g.GroupName 
from Class as c
inner join Group as g on c.Gid = g.Gid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and give alias to the column name itself, something like this:

select 
    c.Gid as 'ClassGid', Class, GroupName, g.Gid as 'Group1Gid'
from 
    Class as c, Group1 as g
where 
    c.Gid = g.Gid